# TDS sync sitecore membership and security between environments, specify deployed items per environment

Tags: sitecore, tds

I am evaluating TDS to see if it solves our requirements, the followings are questions that I need helps;

**Role and memberships**
We like to sync users, roles, security settings, etc between environments using TDS, what are the options to support this requirement?

**Deploy sitecore items**
We have multiple environments which can be categorized into staging and production, we like to specify which items to be deployed by TDS for a specific environment using DeployOnce or AlwaysDeploy property i.e;
1.  Staging environment:  set AlwaysUpdate to all items
2.  Prod environment:  set DeployOnce for some items and AlwaysUpdate for others or just include items to be deployed.
Is there any option to specify which items to be deployed for each environment? One possible solution that I could think of is to create two different TDS projects one for each environment, however there may be other ways.

**Automate syncing from sitecore to TDS project**: is there MSBuild target that can be used from a build script to sync sitecore items to TDS project. Likewise other command which can be perform in Visual Studio such as Get Sitecore Items, Sync with SiteCore, Deploy, etc , can they be triggered from a build script?

**Restrict Syncing direction**: is it possible to specify items can only be synced from sitecore to TDS project in an environment and the same items can sync either direction in another environment?

Comment: FYI, official support for Hedgehog's Team Development for Sitecore (TDS) is handled via email.

Comment: Just a FYI on Role and memberships,
TDS released version 5.1 where you can sync and manage your Sitecore Roles.
http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2014/december/synctdsroles.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**Role and memberships:** No, currently there is no way to bring users and roles into TDS as they are not stored as Sitecore items in the database. Security settings per item will be brought in, as that's stored in a field on the item itself.
Hedgehog mention this in the QnA section of this video:-
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sbx7bk4UEO0&feature=player_detailpage#t=2530s (See 42.10 )

**Deploy sitecore items:** I'm not aware of a way to set deployment properties differently per configuration like that. One possibility is setting 'AlwaysUpdate' once, building to all environments, then setting the 'Exclude from Config' property on the ones you don't want to keep pushing to production, so that it never gets pushed again. Not ideal, but it's an alternative.

**Automate syncing from sitecore to TDS project:** There currently isn't a way you can tap into the TDS webservice to perform these actions from outside of TDS itself.

**Restrict Syncing direction:** Again, not that I'm aware of. If the Sitecore connector is installed on a site, you can do all TDS operations, but you cannot restrict it to a single direction, it's both ways or nothing. The closest thing I can think of regarding this is techphoria414's blog post on restricting builds to non-debug environments....But it's not quite what you're after.
http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/September/Failsafe-for-non-Debug-TDS-Builds

Comment: *Disclaimer* I am a developer of the TDS product.

Good answers Sean. Just to add a little more to it...

* The first two requests are being evaluated for a future version. 
* The third one doesn't really fit the usage of TDS. If someone can provide a valid use case for this please let me know.
* The fourth one has been added to the features request list.